MVC catch event when browser back button is clicked
I am doing an MVC 6 Application.
I have a primary Menu  in _layout Page. Every Manu has a Landing page, and I can navigate throughthat pages.
I use a function to detect the browser's Back button and I can catch the event before returning to the previous page and being able to redirect to another page or do some other thing.
This is the function I have in all the pages
var backButtonHandler = 'SearchResult';// change name for every page
 var backHandledSearchResult = false;
  
 $(function () {
     if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
         window.history.pushState('', null, './');
         $(window).on('popstate', function () {
             if (backButtonHandler == 'SearchResult' && !backHandledSearchResult) {
                 backHandledSearchResult = true;
                     BackToView();
                 }
             }
         });
     }
 });

So every time I click Back button, the function BacktoView() is executed.
The problem I have is that when I click the different options of the Primary menu, the popstate does not change so I can not catch the Browser Back button and do whatever I need.
Every Main Option menu, when it is clicked has it own Landing Page.
The only thing I found to add in that landing pages, reading all the post is this
if (window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type == window.performance.navigation.TYPE_BACK_FORWARD) {
    //do something
  }

But this is executed after the Landing Page is reloading. I need a way to make popstate works when the URL does not change, or something similar.
Any Idea how can I make it work?
thanks
